# Why don't we lose generality when we assume $z^0 > x^0 > y^0$ in the proof of Wick's theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-theorem

In proof's of Wick's theorem it's typically stated (see e.g. page 87 in [Coleman's notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013)) that it's sufficient to consider just one possible time-ordering.  For example for the product $T(\phi(z)\phi(x)\phi(y))$ this would mean that we assume $z^0 > x^0 > y^0$.

Why is this possible without losing generality?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the brackets of the time ordering operator all fields commute. Thus the times are irrelevant as the fields are always ordered so that the assumption is satisfied

Comment: thanks for your answer. My problem, however, is that they assume $z^0 > x^0 > y^0$ and then carry out the proof for $T(\phi(z)\phi(x)\phi(y)) = \phi(z)\phi(x)\phi(y)$. Why is this sufficient?

Comment: As I say, because the time ordering always puts them in the order of increasing time, so it really doesn't matter how the operators begin life inside the brackets

Comment: This justifies  $T(\phi(z)\phi(x)\phi(y)) = T(\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(z)) $ etc. but not that we can carry out the proof by using $T(\phi(z)\phi(x)\phi(y)) = \phi(z)\phi(x)\phi(y)$ and then claiming that this is sufficient to prove the theorem. In particular, we can rewrite the time ordering operator explicitly by using theta functions. Then we a sum over various terms times theta function corresponding to different possible time orderings. Thus I would assume that we need to carry the proof by using this sum and not just for one of the terms. But apparently proving it for one term is sufficient.

Comment: Simply commute the fields to get the correct time ordering and then rename the variables - if you want then at the end of the proof undo the renaming